# Unused Reports in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I want to find out the reports and dashboards which are not being used in PowerBI.Can this be achieved in Powerbi by getting the timestamp when a report or dashboard is accessed using API or is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into the usage metrics that are available:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-usage-metrics

Comment: Yes, I have looked into them and they are helpful. Is there a way to get these metrics using Rest API. It would be helpful. Thank you.@Mark

Comment: Looks like yes you can: see here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-power-bi-activity-log-makes-it-easy-to-download-activity-data-for-custom-usage-reporting/